# Inconsistent data via push update - Multiple Service Workers active at same time?

Tags: javascript, ionic3, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

It seems that my PWA creates multiple service workers, which then leads to inconsistent behavior when receiving push notifications via FCM. (I send Push to all fcmTokens of a user, which works - I successfully received notifications on multiple devices opened at the same time).
For example I open one Tab with the PWA and send a notification to it. Chrome will display the Push notification message, but the opened Tab doesn't get updated. If I click on the notification (to open the same URL the PWA is hosted on), it opens a new tab (now there are 2 tabs with the same URL and the same PWA) and only that Tab gets updated/receives the push notifications. This Tab though works completely as expected now and is how I want the PWA to behave when opened the first time (without clicking the notification). Maybe its also a caching problem and I have two versions of the App running and only one of them receives the Updates?

I noticed the same behavior on smartphone - a new deployed PWA version doesn't receive updates until I click the notification, which sometimes occurs and sometimes doesn't. Even if it does, the App sometimes updates its data and sometimes doesn't.

Please help me to solve the problem and have consistent behavior receiving push notification in my PWA.

I already tried deleting Cache/Application data before launching the PWA, but the problem still consists.

My Service Worker:

```
'use strict';

importScripts('./build/sw-toolbox.js');

const version = 0.83;

self.toolbox.options.cache = {
name: 'ionic-cache'
};

// pre-cache our key assets
self.toolbox.precache(
[
    './build/main.js',
    './build/vendor.js',
    './build/main.css',
    './build/polyfills.js',
    'index.html',
    'manifest.json'
]
);

// dynamically cache any other local assets
self.toolbox.router.any('/*', self.toolbox.fastest);

// for any other requests go to the network, cache,
// and then only use that cached resource if your user goes offline
self.toolbox.router.default = self.toolbox.networkFirst;

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.9/firebase-                            app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.9/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
'messagingSenderId': 'XXXX'
});

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
// The promise that skipWaiting() returns can be safely ignored.
self.skipWaiting();

// Perform any other actions required for your
// service worker to install, potentially inside
// of event.waitUntil();
});

self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
/**event.notification.close();
 event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow("/")); **/
const rootUrl = new URL('/', location).href;
event.notification.close();
// Enumerate windows, and call window.focus(), or open a new     one.
event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll().then(matchedClients => {
        for (let client of matchedClients) {
            if (client.url === rootUrl) {
                return client.focus();
            }
        }
        return clients.openWindow("/");
    })
);
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
let swPushedessageData = payload.data;
swPushedessageData.job = JSON.parse(payload.data.job);
let notificationTitle;
switch (swPushedessageData.action) {
    case 'DELETE':
        notificationTitle = 'Auftrag gelöscht';
        break;
    case 'CREATE':
        notificationTitle = 'Neuer Auftrag zugewiesen';
        break;
    case 'UPDATE':
        notificationTitle = 'Auftragsänderung';
        break;
}

const notificationOptions = {
    icon: '/assets/icon/icon-128x128.png',
    actions: [{action: 'open', title: 'Öffnen'}],
};
send_message_to_all_clients(swPushedessageData);

return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});

function send_message_to_all_clients(msg) {
clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
    clients.forEach(client => {
        send_message_to_client(client, msg).then(m =>         console.log("SW Received Message: " + m));
    })
})
}

function send_message_to_client(client, msg) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const msg_chan = new MessageChannel();

    msg_chan.port1.onmessage = function (event) {
        if (event.data.error) {
            reject(event.data.error);
        } else {
            resolve(event.data);
        }
    };

    client.postMessage(msg, [msg_chan.port2]);
});
}
```

The installation of the Service Worker in the App:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
.then((registration) => {
        const messaging = this.app.messaging();
        this.swIsActive = true;
        messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
        this.checkPushMessagingPermissionAfterLogin();
        this.swRegistration = registration;
    })
```